# How to get recently used and closed apps in android Lollipop version?

Tags: android

The following code is working for  before Lollipop versions, but after Lollipop, it's not working. Any suggestion?

```
Log.e(TAG,"-----RECENT APPS-----\n");
for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo task : recentTasks) {
    Intent baseIntent = task.baseIntent;
    if (baseIntent != null) {
        String text = baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
        String appName = "";
        try {
            appName = (String) pack.getApplicationLabel(
                    pack.getApplicationInfo(text, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Recent Apps : " + text + " :" + appName);
        recent_task_map.put(text, (String) appName);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "RecentTask :" + " No Recent task");
    }
}
```

Comment: this code works on every version, what will not work on 5+ devices is `ActivityManager#getRecentTasks()` method

Comment: this code giving foreground task name only

Comment: it is giving only foreground app name

Comment: so what does not work? `getPackageName()`, `getApplicationLabel()`, `getApplicationInfo()`? `task.baseIntent` is null?

Comment: please give working code for lollipop version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRecentTasks()` is deprecated and will only work for devices having API level < 21

If you wish to do so for devices having API level > 21, you can use `getAppTasks()` to get the list of tasks related to the calling application.

For more information, check out the below links :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int%2C%20int)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks()

Comment: List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = manager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);